# Iam using Toshiba Elite with windows 7 64 bits , can I convert to bits 32?

Tags: windows-7

Where can I find Free software to convert windows 7 to 32 bits ?

Thanks

Paulus

Comment: And why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you have more than 4GB of RAM then doing this is stupid. You would be better of replacing the software or hardware you are having trouble with.

Comment: Actually, with Address space randomisation it is a bad idea to use 32 bit if you have more than 512MiB RAM. Way less than 4GiB. @OP: See the duplicate posts. Basically, reformat and reinstall, then restore data you wanted to keep from a backup (or keep it on a second partition).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "convert" Windows to 32 bit.  You will have to do a reinstall of the OS with a 32 bit media.

Answer (score 1):

you cant convert a program from 32 to 64 or inverse by yourself. but most 32bit programs runs on 64bit OS
. if a 32bit program cant load on a 64bit OS you need find a 64bit version of that program.
anyway the 64bit OS is more powerful and faster that 32bit OS if you have more that 4GB RAM. so do not downgrade your OS 64 bit to OS 32bit . just find your program in 64bit version or if you insist, install a virtual machine and install a 32bit OS on it , so you can run your 32bit program on that virtual OS :)